# Find evolute of a curve

Tags: differential-geometry

Given a function $r(t)=(a\cos t,b\sin t)$, I want to find the evolute of a curve, because I can't find a physical parameter and I don't know if I can use this type:
$$
r_1(t)=r(t)+\frac{\overline N(t)}{\overline k(t)},
$$
where $\overline N(t)$ is a continuous first vertical vector and $\overline k(t)$ is marked curvature.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! This is not quite clear to me. What do you mean with ‘the injected curve’? That $r(t)$ is a parametric representation of a curve?

Comment: @Bernard hmm I think in this occasion its the same with center of curvature. Οr maybe induced curves?

Comment: If it is indeed a parametric representation, the curve is an ellipse with semi-axes $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @Bernard I guess its better to say that I want to find the evolute of the curve?

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipseEvolute.html

Comment: @Superd: Yes – it's clearer now.